Problems with Docker container configuration to specific IP addresses for Kafka and Zookeeper
I would like to run a Kafka cluster on one of my servers using a series of Docker containers. The associated Docker containers should not listen to 0.0.0.0, but to the internal and external IP of the server so that firewall rules still work correctly.
Below you will find my corresponding docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'
services:
  kafka-ui:
    container_name: kafka-ui
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka1
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka1:19091
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_JMXPORT: 9997
      SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH: /kafkaui
      AUTH_TYPE: "LOGIN_FORM"
      SPRING_SECURITY_USER_NAME: test
      SPRING_SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD: test
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.4
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUMES_PATH}/data/zookeeper/data:/data
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUMES_PATH}/data/zookeeper/datalog:/datalog
  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.1
    hostname: kafka1
    ports:
      - "111.111.111.111:9091:9091"
      - "192.168.0.0:9091:9091"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19091,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://111.111.111.111:9091,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL_2://192.168.0.0:9091
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL_2:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "False"
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUMES_PATH}/data/kafka1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  kafka2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.1
    hostname: kafka2
    ports:
      - "111.111.111.111:9092:9092"
      - "192.168.0.0:9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka2:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://111.111.111.111:9092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL_2://192.168.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL_2:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "False"
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUMES_PATH}/data/kafka2/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  kafka3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.1
    hostname: kafka3
    ports:
      - "111.111.111.111:9093:9093"
      - "192.168.0.0:9093:9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka3:19093,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://111.111.111.111:9093,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL_2://192.168.0.0:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL_2:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "False"
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUMES_PATH}/data/kafka3/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - "111.111.111.111:9000:9093"
      - "192.168.0.0:9000:9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: "kafka1:19091"
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
      - kafka3

However, I get the following error message when starting the containers:
2024-07-24 06:24:51,139 WARN  [parallel-2] o.a.k.c.ClientUtils: Couldn't resolve server kafka1:19091 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka1
2024-07-24 06:24:51,151 ERROR [parallel-2] c.p.k.u.s.StatisticsService: Failed to collect cluster local info
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while creating AdminClient for Cluster local
        at com.provectus.kafka.ui.service.AdminClientServiceImpl.lambda$createAdminClient$5(AdminClientServiceImpl.java:56)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$28(Mono.java:3783)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:135)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4480)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4495)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:427)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runAsync(FluxPublishOn.java:440)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:527)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:551)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:488)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.create(Admin.java:134)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient.create(AdminClient.java:39)
        at com.provectus.kafka.ui.service.AdminClientServiceImpl.lambda$createAdminClient$2(AdminClientServiceImpl.java:53)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.call(MonoSupplier.java:67)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:127)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:89)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:508)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
2024-07-24 06:24:51,158 DEBUG [parallel-2] c.p.k.u.s.ClustersStatisticsScheduler: Metrics updated for cluster: local

I have also tried to bring each of these docker containers together in a custom network to resolve the names correctly. Unfortunately without success.
Can anyone help me find the correct configuration?
Thanks in advance.
